# Findwindow, FindWindowEx and SendMessage on locked PC

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I just want to ask,does Findwindow, FindWindowEx and SendMessage work when PC is locked?

I have a Windows 7 pc (work pc) by the way.

I'm trying to automate file download but I'm having a hard time bypassing the file download dialog box. I was able to do it using SendKeys but found out it doesn't work when PC is locked.

I'm automating a task that will run before I get to work. It's a score report.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Sorry if I didn't include this information, but the link or download file link is generated by a javascript/jquery funtion. I the link only has the numeric value that increments every second. And I can't figure out the pattern, I tried incrementing from the last download link figure but it did not work.

Comment: Why not connecting directly to the URL and download the files from your program (and getting rid of the browser "node") ?

Comment: Hi @CristiFati sorry but the site doesn't have a direct link, but an autogenerated one by a javascript function

Comment: How about finding the download dialog window, then finding its _OK_ button child window and sending to that one the `BM_CLICK` message?

Comment: @CristiFati i'm actually there but my question is, does findwindo,findwindowex and sendmessage work even if the pc is locked?

Comment: @vade: If you are using an embedded browser for the purpose of running the javascript, you can intercept the browser's `BeforeNavigate/2` event, check the provided URL if see if it is the file being downloaded, and if so then cancel the event and download the file in your own code.

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau for the idea but what function do I use to capture the download link?

Comment: @vade: The URL is provided to you in the `BeforeNavigate/2` event handler. That is why I said you have to check the URL, to make sure you only block download navigations and not other navigations.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. Does it capture anything or any link when its about to load? I was able to automate IE 8 using IE object using the getelementbyid and  .Click. Will the BeforeNavigate2 work with that?

Sorry if I cant post my code, Im not at work right now. I cant do it as well at work due to restrictions.

Comment: Short answer: no, window messaging functions (including but not limited to FindWindow, SendMessage, etc.) may not work as expected when the workstation is locked.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar macro that use Findwindow, FindWindowEx, SendMessage, PostMessage and sndPlaySound functions. It run successfully when I lock my pc via "CTRL+ALT+DEL > Lock Computer" (Windows 7-32bit). But you should test it for a long time, especially if new Windows appear during process.

Comment: I was able to automate my report but not when the pc is locked, my workstation runs on Windows 7 64 bit. Is there a difference between those apis for 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: @vade my macro uses only this constants `WM_CLOSE, BM_CLICK, WM_PASTE, EM_SETSEL, WM_CLEAR, CB_SETCURSEL`. It is not too complicated maybe some message beheave different than others. But if your macro works when pc is not locked, it shouldn't be beacuse of 64 bit version.

Comment: thanks again noas for the info. I have another question, does it matter how you lock the screen? Does it only work using the ctrl-alt-del to lock the screen?

Comment: @vade It works when screensaver lock computer when computer is idle. But I think there will be no differance which method you lock the computer.